# Understanding user details in git

Tags: git, github, version-control

I've just created a brand new repository on Github. My Github username is foo. However, after adding files, committing, and running the `git remote add origin ____` and `git push -u origin master` commands, I get prompted for my Github credentials. I enter them and the push goes smoothly, except when I look at the repository on Github, the commit came from someone not called foo. I guess it's pulling in the username from somewhere else, but it certainly has no relation to my Github account.

My question is not how to fix this, but more why this happens. Why is the name of the committer independent from the name of the Github user whose credentials get supplied? If, when I'm asked for my Github credentials, I enter the username foo, how does it make sense for the commit to not be in the name of foo?

Answer (score 3):

There are two "users" in play here:

1. The username and email address you commit with
2. The authentication data you use for your remote, in this case GitHub

These are completely separate and can be completely different.

To specify the first, ie. what name and email address you will commit with, either:

1. Issue `git config` commands to set these values
2. or edit the `.gitconfig` file directly

The `.gitconfig` file is placed in your home directory which would be `~` on most linux-compatible systems, or `C:\Users\<your username>` (or similar depending on your installation) on Windows.

To issue the commands:

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name Here"
git config --global user.email "Your email address here"
```

To edit the config file, open it up in your favorite text editor and either locate and change, or add the following:

```
[user]
    name = Your Name Here
    email = Your Email Address Here
```

Be aware that there is no checking here, other than perhaps to prompt for these values if they are completely missing, but you can specify anything, which means you can easily commit with the following:

```
[user]
    name = Donald Duck
    email = donald@gmail.com
```

---

**Note!** You can also specify/override this locally for a specific repository, in which case the `.gitconfig` file is stored inside the `.git` folder and named just `config`, and you can issue the same commands as above to change it, just omitting the `--global` part.

---

Your authentication data for github was, as you stated, prompted for when you tried to push. Exactly where these are stored, in case you need to update them, depends on your operating system and/or "credential helper", of which there are several to choose from.

Answer (score 2):

Git gets your user name and email from the `user.name` and `user.email` configuration settings. These settings are used when creating new commits locally. You can set these with:

```
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
git config --global user.email "your.email@example.com"
```

Git settings can be stored in two different locations, and are used in the following priority order:

1. The `.git/config` file in the repository directory.
2. The `.gitconfig` file in your home directory.

You can see what the settings are by using a command like:

```
git config --show-origin user.email
```

The `--show-origin` switch shows you where the setting is actually coming from.

Comment: Thanks, however my question was more about what the technical reason is for having to set the name and email like this in the first place is. If I'm entering my Github credentials then Github should know what my name and email are. And it seems strange to me that I can commit in the name of something other than my Github username.

Comment: @Cal: The thing to remember is that Git is independent of Github. When you make a commit locally, you're not involving Github (the service) at all. It's not until you *push* that you involve Github. But by that time the commit has already been made locally, and nothing about the commit can be changed at that point. Your Github credentials are used to determine whether you are allowed to push your (already created) commit up to Github.